# How to insert one linked list behind another?

Tags: c++, linked-list

For an assignment, I need to add one objects linked list to the back of another.  I have this:

```
WORD you("you");//where you's linked list now contains y o u
WORD are("are");//where are's linked list now contains a r e
```

and I want to do this:

```
you.Insert(are,543);//(anything greater they the current objects length is
                    //attached to the back. So that 543 can be anything > you's length
```

so Now, you's linked linked list should contain:

```
y o u a r e
```

I was able to insert in the front, and anywhere in between the letters, but when I try to insert in the back the program crashes instantly.  Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong? I tried using the debugger and it points to one line, but I cant figure out what is wrong. I've marked the line as a coming in the function:

```
void WORD::Insert(WORD & w, int pos)
{
if(!w.IsEmpty())
{
    alpha_numeric *r = w.Cpy();
    alpha_numeric *loc;

    (*this).Traverse(loc,pos);//pasing Traverse a pointer to a node and the     position in the list

    //if(loc == 0)
    //{
    //  alpha_numeric *k = r;//k is pointing to the begin. of the copied words list
    //  while(k -> next != 0)
    //  {
    //      k = k -> next;//k goes to the back 
    //  }
    //  k -> next = front;//k(the back) is now the front of *this
    //  front = r;//front now points to r, the copy
    //}
    else if(loc == back)
    {

        back -> next = r; //<<<-------DEBUGGER SAYS ERROR HERE?
        length += w.Length();
        while(back -> next!= 0)
        {
            back = back -> next;
        }
    }
    /*else
    {
        alpha_numeric *l = r;

        while(l -> next != 0)
        {
            l = l -> next;
        }
        l -> next = loc -> next;
        loc -> next = r;
    }
    length += w.Length();
}*/
}
```

Also, here is the Traverse function  I used if it helps

```
void WORD::Traverse(alpha_numeric * & p, const int & pos)
{
if(pos <= 1)
{
    p = 0;
}
else if( pos > (*this).Length())
{
    p = back;
}
else
{
    p = front;
    for(int i = 1; i < pos - 1; i++)
    {
        p = p -> next;
    }
}

}
```

**I DECLARED BACK AS A POINTER IN THE PRIVATE SECTION OF THE CLASS. *back**

This is how I put it in the constructor

```
WORD::WORD()
{
alpha_numeric *p;

front = new alpha_numeric;
front = 0;
length = 0;
back = front;

for(p = front; p != 0; p = p -> next)
{
    back = back -> next;
}
}
```

Comment: We haven't seen all of your code, but the obvious conclusion is that `back` doesn't point to a valid `alpha_numeric` object; instead it's 0 or garbage.

Comment: I don't notice that `back` is in scope.  It's not a global variable, is it?  (It probably shouldn't be.)

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill ill post more, I declared back as a pointer in the private section of the class. ill post how I put it in the constructor

Comment: Now I'm even more confused -- the new code added at the end can't possibly do anything useful?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill when the object gets created, it assigns back to point to the last node in the linked list

Comment: But `front` is 0? And if we left that line out, `front` points to a single object?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill   ohhhh true....

Comment: And I believe -- I'd have to use pencil and paper to make sure, it's late here! -- I believe that if `front` starts out somewhere sensible, then `back` ends up equal to the value of the `next` member of the last node in the list, which is `0`.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill well i know front is right because we are learning this without headers right now so front has to be null, so i have to figure out whats up with back

Comment: When the debugger indicates the line of code with the problem, you can ask the debugger the value of the variables in the routine. So you should check to see if `back` has a valid value in it or not.

Comment: It looks like you've been doing plenty of trial-and-error programming. Get a pencil and paper and draw boxes and arrows that show what *should* happen. Then go through your code line by line and draw what *actually* happens. Then translate what *should* happen into C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*back is not pointing to the correct node in the Traverse function.  It should look like this:

```
else if( pos > (*this).Length())
{
    alpha_numeric *k = (*this).front;
    while( k -> next != 0)
    {
        k = k -> next;
    }
    back = k;
    p = back;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect your problem stems from not updating `back` in the `if(loc==0)` block when the list is empty.

In this case, `back` is left `== 0` and will fail an append operation.